# If $int\overline{X} = int\overline{Y} = \emptyset$ then $int(\overline{X\cup Y}) = \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of a metric space. If $int\overline{X} = int\overline{Y} = \emptyset$ then $int(\overline{X\cup Y}) = \emptyset$.

I know that $int(\overline{X\cup Y}) = int(\overline{X}\cup \overline{Y})$ and so I'm trying to prove the more general statement 
$$
int(X) = int(Y) = \emptyset \implies int(X\cup Y) = \emptyset
$$
which seems true to me but I not getting the proof.

What I tried so far is to consider an $x\in int(X\cup Y)$, so there is a open ball $B_x$ that is contained in $X\cup Y$ but it cannot be contained in $X$ or $Y$ because these have empty interior. But I don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The more general statement isn't true: consider the case $X$ is the set of rational numbers and $Y$ is the set of irrational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the statement you were expecting to hold does not, as Daniel Schepler illustratively pointed out. There is however a series of elementary propositions valid over any topological space $(X, \mathscr{T})$:

> Proposition 1. For any $M, N \subseteq X$ it holds that $\overline{M \cup N}=\overline{M} \cup \overline{N}$ **(finite additivity of the closure operator)**.
>
> Proposition 2. For any subset $M \subseteq X$ and open subset $U \in \mathscr{T}$ it holds that $U \cap \overline{M} \subseteq \overline{U \cap M}$.
>
> Corollary 1. If $T \subseteq X$ is a dense subset (i.e. $\overline{T}=X$), then $\overline{U}=\overline{U \cap T}$.
>
> Corollary 2. The intersection of two dense open subsets is also dense and open.

If $F, G$ are two closed sets of empty interior, then their complementaries are open dense subsets and subsequently so is their intersection (corollary 2). Hence $F \cup G$ has empty interior.

Comment: And all of this is valid in any kind of topological space....+1

Comment: Whenever possible, I like to be as general in my approach as possible (to illustrate the richness of facts which unfold from a handful of well laid-out axioms).

Comment: Many Q's  about metric spaces on this site are applicable to all spaces, or all Hausdorff spaces. It seems to me that many of them are from students who have had  little or even no study of top. spaces in general. This may be due the order of their course material.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is called nowhere dense iff the interior of its closure is empty iff the complement of $X$ contains a dense and open subset iff every non-empty open subset $O$ contains a non-empty open subset $O'$ that misses $X$.

As the finite intersection of dense and open subsets is dense and open, by de Morgan, the finite union of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense. Or using the final characterisation: first pick $O'$ to avoid $X$ and an even smaller one inside $O'$ to also avoid $Y$.